# "Отсутствует доступ к отдельным столбцам" при отсутствии объединенных ячеек

Tags: vba, ms-word

Есть программа, которая выводит табличный отчет в Word.
Программа на Delphi, работа ведется через OleVariant, но это не суть важно, проблема остается и при использовании чистого VBA.

Суть проблемы: при попытке доступа к колонке выводится ошибка "Отсутствует доступ к отдельным столбцам, поскольку ячейки таблицы имеют разную ширину"

```
Sub Макрос2()
    ActiveDocument.Range.Text = ""

    '' //если следующие 2 строчки закомментировать - ошибка выходит далеко не всегда
    '' //как это связано - не знаю, но в коде Delphi этих строк нет, 
    '' //а там ошибка появляется гарантированно.
    '' // оставляем как есть - ошибка проявляется всегда.
    Application.ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdNormalView
    Application.ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdWebView

    ActiveDocument.Range.Text = _
        vbTab & "asdf asdf" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "asdf asdf" & vbCrLf _
      & vbTab & "asdf asdf" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "asdf asdf" & vbCrLf _
      & vbTab & "asdf asdf" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "asdf asdf" & vbCrLf _
      & vbTab & "asdf asdf" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "asdf asdf" & vbCrLf _

    ActiveDocument.Range.ConvertToTable (vbTab)

    '' //ошибка здесь, при доступе к Item(1)
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns.Item(1).Width = 11
    ''// ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(1).Width = 11 тоже не работает
End Sub
```

Просмотрел другие вопросы по этой ошибке - везде пишут, что она связана с объединением ячеек. Однако в этом коде никакого объединения нет и количество колонок в строках идентично!

Можно ли (и как) обойти это?

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать данной строкой? если установить ширину столбца, то `Columns.Item(1)` замените на `Columns(1)`

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков так тоже не работает. Ошибка та же, воспроизводится стабильно.

Comment: в VBA не работает? какую ошибку выдаёт? у меня без ошибок срабатывает.

Comment: хм, очень интересно. выдаёт ошибку, но если продолжить выполнение, то отрабатывает. нужно поковыряться.

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков Не работает как в VBA, так и при доступе через OLEVariant в Delphi. К сожалению, при выдаче ошибки ширина столбца и остальные параметры (выравнивание и т.п. ) не выставляются, что сводит на нет все форматирование таблицы.

Comment: попробуйте добавить `activedocument.tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow` перед изменением ширины столбца

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков увы, это не решает проблемы. Форматирование "едет", растягивание таблицы по ширине в моем случае мешает (предположим, что таблица узкая и должна располагаться по центру). Кроме того, даже в примере из вопроса таким образом удается установить ширину только первых двух столбцов. Дальше (начиная с третьего, когда ширина первых двух уже установлена) - `runtime error "4608" Значение лежит вне допустимого диапазона.`

Comment: можно `wdAutoFitWindow` заменить на `wdAutoFitFixed`, чтобы таблица не растягивалась на весь экран. И уж тогда приведите остальной код, чтобы понять, откуда ошибка

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков остальной код слишком большой и к тому же выполняется в Delphi.Здесь я привел минимальный рабочий пример, гарантированно воспроизводящий ошибку и не завязанный на среду разработки. Ваше крайнее предложение решает мою проблему, прошу оформить как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед изменением ширины столбца вставьте код:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitFixed
```

Параметры могут быть следующими: `wdAutoFitFixed, wdAutoFitContent, wdAutoFitWindow`. Первый указывает, что ширина таблицы фиксированная, второй - подбор по содержимому, третий - растягивать таблицу по ширине окна.
Подробнее можно почитать на [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ff820953)